# Drupal: How long should it take to rebuild permissions

Tags: drupal, permissions, acl

I have just installed the [ACL](http://drupal.org/project/acl) and [Content Access](http://drupal.org/project/content_access) module. Imedietly after enabling them I was asked to rebuild the permissions. All perfectly normal I am told.

However, I set the 'rebuild' permissions page running about 40 minutes ago and it still says 'Initializing'. **How long should it take?** Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just refresh the page. The perms get rebuilt in a few seconds :).

Comment: Have done … a couple of times. Is there anything I can do / check?

Comment: A little over an hour and it's sorted ;-)

Answer (score 4):

The standard "rebuild perms" duration is roughly proportional to the number of node multiplied by the number of access modules enabled.

On a site with 100k nodes, you can easily take more than 24hours to rebuild permissions. Which means you simply don't want to do it interactively. But you can launch that rebuild from drush or use one of the faster non-standard rebuild methods.

Comment: How would you rebuild the permissions on a production site?

Comment: Basically: run a CLI (drush) script which loops on module_invoke_all('node_access_records', $node) for all nodes builds a data file (non-DB) in that loop. Then, once it is complete, TRUNCATE node_access and LOAD DATA INFILE <the file> INTO node_access. 

And finally, tell Drupal it's done by invoking node_access_needs_rebuild(FALSE);

Refine as necessary for your RAM/load limitations and the possibility of node rights changing during the rebuild loop. A mildly elaborated variant of this allowed us to drop rebuilds from 24 hours to 30 minutes.

Comment: `FGM`: could you please share your custom Drush script? That would help us a lot.

Comment: @FGM Hi FGM - Would you have a copy of the script you put together for this?

Comment: @BeardedGeek That was on a customer site years ago: I no longer have access to it, but it was more or less just what I explained above. Take care with LOAD DATA INFILE: this needs local access to the MySQL server. Might need a different solution if you run on PGSQL or MS SQL Server.

Answer (score 3):

To do it via drush, use:

drush php-eval 'node_access_rebuild();'

Answer (score 0):

Note:  If it takes you 24 hours to rebuild on a site with 100K nodes,  something is wrong.  It takes us about 30min on a site with 200K+ FWIW.  For a smaller site it should be much less;  I suspect you were experiencing an error of some kind.

Comment: node_access_rebuild() calls node_load() for each node - so possible issue can be a lot of modules that implement hook_load() and perform some heave operations there.

Answer (score 0):

A quick solution can be just change your theme back to default GARLAND theme and than try again rebuilding permissions, most probably it will work. As sometime it is JS errors which is  causing it to stuck on Initialization.

And if your site has too much data (node like 100k , 200K) you can also use this script by placing it in a php file in Drupal root and running it. The code is under the heading

WSODs Due to Specific Modules -> Node Access

on this link :

http://drupal.org/node/158043